# Factorial and combinations question.

Tags: permutations, factorial, combinations

Any help with these would be greatly appreciated...

1) How many arrangements are there of the letters of the word SAUSAGES ? if the A’s must be together and the S’s apart? (answer apparently 240 ways)

2) A team of 5 people is to be chosen from 7 Girls and 6 Boys, how many teams are possible if there must be more girls than boys and Julie (a girl) can’t be on the same team as Michael (a boy). 
(answer apparently 661)

Thanks a lot. I really need urgent help with this.

Comment: We help those who help themselves. What do you know about this kind of problem? What techniques have you learned?

Comment: For the arrangements to be defined, y00 must specify how many letters are taken.

Comment: I think I managed to find the answer to the second problem by subtracting the combinations of them both being in the team from the total possibilities, however I'm still struggling with the first question. @Alex hinted at the "inclusion-exclusion principle" however I personally have never heard of it and would prefer to keep the answer within the realms of my current knowledge. My current solution is to subtract the the number of ways in which the S's are together from 7!/3! (the number of ways that the a's are together) but it seems to be a very lengthy method...

Answer (score 1):

Hints:
1) use the inclusion-exclusion principle,

2) If there are more girls than boys on the committee of five, you have three choices: $(0,5), (1,4), (2,3)$. Then you choose $j$ from the set of boys and $5-j$ from the set of girls.